# sphinx-autoapi fails to combine class and __init__ docstrings (autoapi_python_class_content = 'both')

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, read-the-docs

sphinx-autoapi allows to combine the class docstrings and the `__init__` docstrings using the [`autoapi_python_class_content = 'both'`](https://sphinx-autoapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/config.html#confval-autoapi_python_class_content) option.

However, even with this option set ([`conf.py`](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway-documentation/blob/e24d0aa0b74e5daffc06ad05a8ce09c1b421ed04/sphinx/conf.py#LL94C30-L94C30)), it fails to properly combine the docstrings:

The class [SingleOutputEcospold2Importer](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/blob/d7d9cf8d4fb9851a2a3b1041968d8768c2903d64/bw2io/importers/ecospold2.py#L35)

```
class SingleOutputEcospold2Importer(LCIImporter):

    """
    Class for importing single-output ecospold2 format LCI databases.

    Raises
    ------
    MultiprocessingError
        If an error occurs during multiprocessing.
    """

    format = u"Ecospold2"

    def __init__(
        self,
        dirpath,
        db_name,
        extractor=Ecospold2DataExtractor,
        use_mp=True,
        signal=None,
    ):

        """
        Initializes the SingleOutputEcospold2Importer class instance.

        Parameters
        ----------
        dirpath : str
            Path to the directory containing the ecospold2 file.
        db_name : str
            Name of the LCI database.
        extractor : class
            Class for extracting data from the ecospold2 file, by default Ecospold2DataExtractor.
        use_mp : bool
            Flag to indicate whether to use multiprocessing, by default True.
        signal : object
            Object to indicate the status of the import process, by default None.
        """
```

is rendered as

[image]

Comment: I think it's working as intended. It's concatenating the two strings, but since your `__init__` docstring is indented more, the combined string contains the long list of "exceptions" that you see rendered.

Comment: Not ideal, but try dedenting the *contents* of the `__init__` docstring (not the opening `"""`, just the text inside the quotes).

Comment: Unfortunately, dedenting the content does not change the sphinx html output.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know the format used by Sphinx. If you were defining this as a single docstring, how would you "end" the list of exceptions so that "Initializes the SingleOutputEcospold2Importer class instance." would be a new paragraph, and not part of the exception list? Maybe add an additional blank line to the end of the class docstring and/or to the beginning of the `__init__` docstring?

Comment: Indeed - it seems that the lack of an empty line in the class docstring caused the issue. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `autoapi_python_class_content = 'both'` option is fairly simple: it literally just concatenates two (normalized) strings. In the current case, the concatenation just continues the list of exceptions where it left off, because there's no division between it and the "header" for the `__init__` method.

The solution is to ensure that the concatenation results in the single string you want. This means modifying one (or both) strings in a way that you wouldn't if you weren't planning on them to be concatenated, but I don't think that's avoidable.

Here, you can add a blank line to the end of the class docstring to "terminate" the exception list explicitly, rather than simply letting the string end.

```
class SingleOutputEcospold2Importer(LCIImporter):

    """
    Class for importing single-output ecospold2 format LCI databases.

    Raises
    ------
    MultiprocessingError
        If an error occurs during multiprocessing.

    """

    format = u"Ecospold2"

    ...
```